# jpa native query not returning all values

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I am using jpa native query , but its not returning values from salias it returns values from S

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("Select S.\"MESSAGE\",S.\"DESTINATION\",S.\"SENT_DATE\",S.\"CLIENT_TRACKING_ID\",S.\"MESSAGE_COST\",S.\"sTId\",salias.\"STATUS\",salias.timeDate from \"sent_sms_view\" S left join ( Select Distinct on (\"SMS_ID\") R.\"SMS_ID\",R.\"STATUS\",R.timeDate from \"sms_receipt_view\" R  Order By R.\"SMS_ID\",R.timeDate Desc)As salias on S.\"SYSTEM_TRACKING_ID\"=salias.\"SMS_ID\" where S.Id_systemUser=:systemUser and S.\"CLIENT_TRACKING_ID\"=:cTId");

        query.setParameter("cTId", cTId);
        query.setParameter("systemUser", systemUser);
        if (query.getResultList().size() > 0){
        List<Object> resultat = query.getResultList();
```

This is the Postgres query and it works fine

```
Select S."MESSAGE",S."DESTINATION",S."SENT_DATE",S."CLIENT_TRACKING_ID",S."MESSAGE_COST",S."sTId" ,salias."STATUS",salias.timeDate
from "sent_sms_view" S
left join ( Select Distinct on ("SMS_ID") R."SMS_ID",R."STATUS",R.timeDate from "sms_receipt_view" R  Order By R."SMS_ID",R.timeDate Desc)As salias
on S."SYSTEM_TRACKING_ID"=salias."SMS_ID"
where S.Id_systemUser='101' and S."CLIENT_TRACKING_ID" ='abda';
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you using quotes in your query?

Comment: Database is having coloumns in that way thats why..I cant change database structure @Makoto

Comment: The quotes in your query have nothing to do with the database unless the columns are using reserved keywords, which I don't believe they are...

Comment: If i do not use quotes it does not work. Is that causing problem in returning values?

Comment: Potentially not, but I'm confused at your query.  What would it look like if you were just doing straight-up SQL?  Why do you have a select clause in your join?

Comment: Because i want to get unique row from sms_receipt_view on the basis of SMS_ID coloumn thats why i am adding subquery. @Makoto

Comment: The query doen't work if i do not use those quotes @NeilStockton

Comment: Again, the query doesn't make sense with the SELECT clause in the JOIN query.  Again, could you share with us what the query *should* be if you wrote it out in pure SQL?

Comment: Please check the query @Makoto

Comment: @NeilStockton this means it gives me error regarding that parameter does not exist.

Comment: try to rewrite join select statement from distinct to group by or something. i've heard many times that there are problems with java based query parses  have some hiccups parsing, getting and validating parameter conditions with complicated queries

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing what you might be trying to do, since you haven't told us, but here's how I'm guessing it should probably look like:

```
SELECT S."MESSAGE", S."DESTINATION", S."SENT_DATE", S."CLIENT_TRACKING_ID", S."MESSAGE_COST", S."sTId", salias."STATUS", salias.timeDate
FROM "sent_sms_view" S
INNER JOIN "sms_receipt_view" AS salias on (S."SYSTEM_TRACKING_ID" = salias."SMS_ID")
WHERE S.Id_systemUser=:systemUser AND S."CLIENT_TRACKING_ID"=:cTId
```

However I don't see why you would have numerical IDs, such as `Id_systemUser` stored as strings. In fact that variable name indicates horrible database design. CamelCasing combined with underscores is something you must categorically avoid.

And you must never call `query.getResultList()` twice if you're looking for the same results. Simply store the `List` to a local variable and then use it.